# Footer stucked at the middle HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make my footer go at the bottom for the past 2 hours and I can't quite get it fixed at the bottom part. My html code is in here ``https://pastebin.com/UE7NfbWB while I only use bootstrap for my css and I didn't change or add something major, just adding some colors. The red rectangular area is the free space like something is jammed in it. [image]

Comment: Do you have your css code available?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VMyNpNVd I have it in here

Comment: Give body min-height of 100vh ` body { min-height:100vh; } `